# increase proxy_send_timeout and proxy_read_timeout ingress nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Im running deployments on GKE,

using `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.12.0` image as  nginx-ingress-controller

Im trying to increase `proxy_send_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout` following to this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.12.0/docs/user-guide/annotations.md)

here is my ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 100m
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.my.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: front-app
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.my.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-app
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.old.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-app
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.my.com
    - api.my.com
    secretName: tls-secret-my-com
  - hosts:
    - api.old.com
    secretName: tls-secret-old-com
```

still this does not change the `proxy_send_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout`

requests which take longer than 60s (default nginx timeout) are closed

I see this log:

```
[error] 20967#20967: * upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.456.789.12, server: api.my.com, request: "GET /v1/example HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://11.22.3.44:4000/v3/example", host: "api.my.com", referrer: "https://app.my.com/"
```

when I go into the nginx pod:

```
> kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-xxxx-yyyy -n ingress-nginx -- bash
> cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

output:

```
server {
    server_name _ ;

    listen 80 default_server  backlog=511;
    location / {
        # Custom headers to proxied server

        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
        proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
        proxy_read_timeout                      60s;
```

`proxy_send_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout` are set to `60s` and not `360s` as I configured on the ingress

so I tried changing manually the timeout on `nginx` conf, and then I did not get the timeout on the client, but every time the nginx is restarted the values are returned to the default `60s`

how can I configure currectly the timeouts on the ingress?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Based on : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2007#issuecomment-374856607

```
I had the same problem and discovered that the following do not work:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy‑read‑timeout: 1800
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy‑read‑timeout: 1800s
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy‑read‑timeout: "1800s"

What does work is:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy‑read‑timeout: "1800"
```

Try to change the value in the annotation to '360'. The value needs to be a number.

Comment: To be clear, it has to be a quoted number! "360" would be good but NOT 360, 360s or "360s"

Answer (score 14):

As per [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-timeouts) you should use numerical values treated as a string.

Example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp-domain-local
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: webapp.domain.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: webapplication
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: how can i change this to connection to close instead of keep-alive

Answer (score 4):

Use the annotation as shown below

```
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
```

It should reflect in the nginx conf file as below

```
                        proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;
                        proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;
```